# Run a Bash script as root with Objective-C / Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bash

Given that there is a file called copystuff in the Resources folder in a an xCode project, and that file reads:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp -R /Users/someuser/Documents /Users/admin/Desktop
```

And if this bit of code below is linked to a button in IB ... it will copy the /Users/someuser/Documents directory to /Users/admin when the button is pressed in a Cocoa app... It works when app is launched in an admin account ( using OS X 10.5.x here) ...

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
pathForResource:@"copystuff" ofType:@"sh"], nil]];
[task launch];
```

My question is.. is there a way to have NSTask run a script running as root while this code  is called from a non-admin account? Or asked another way..can Objective-C be coded to run scripts from say /usr/bin as root from a non-admin account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against using an external script like this. It's much better to do this with `NSFileManager` and keep this inside of controlled code. But to the question of how to become root, you want to look at [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html). This site will walk you through how to create an application that escalates its privileges, including the appropriate UI elements for it.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding what you want to do, you're trying to have a non-privileged user be able to perform a privileged action without needing to authenticate?

setuid shell scripts are considered a gigantic security risk, so they're disallowed by the kernel.  If you want to write a separate executable program, however, you can set the set-user-ID-on-execution or set-group-ID-on-execution bits on it and get the behaviour you want.  Be careful, you're now in the land of big potential security problems...

[man chmod](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) for more information.

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
$ echo "Hello, world!" > file
$ sudo chown root file
$ sudo chmod 600 file
$ cat file
cat: file: Permission denied
```

But I can write a program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  setuid(0);
  system("cat file");
  return 0;
}
```

Which can do what we'd like:

```
$ cc -Wall -o app main.c
$ chown root app
$ chmod 4755 app
$ ./app
Hello, world!
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I am trying to do... To be less cryptic, I have 3 accounts on an OS 10.5 image deployed in an educational setting. ( admin,teacher,student). Teacher and student accounts are non-admin.. On a request, I am trying to allow the non-admin Teacher account the ability to copy items from the student account to the Teacher desktop..The app runs successfully from the admin account, but I want to be able to give the Teacher some of these prvileged actions without giving them the admin password....

Comment: You might have better luck looking into more sophisticated permissions options, like access control lists: http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/acl.html